# How to get most popular name by year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am practicing SQL in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (not a homework question), and have a table `Names`. The table shows baby names by year, with columns `Sex` (gender of name), `N` (number of babies having that name), `Yr` (year), and `Name` (the name itself).

I need to write a query using only one `SELECT` statement that returns the most popular baby name by year, with gender, the year, and the number of babies named. So far I have;

```
SELECT *
From Names
ORDER By N DESC;
```

Which gives the highest values of N in DESC order, repeating years. I need to limit it to only the highest value in each year, and everything I have tried to do so has thrown errors. Any advice you can give me for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Off the top of my my head**, something like the following would normally let you do it in (technically) one SELECT statment. That statement includes sub-SELECTs, but I'm not immediately seeing an alternative that wouldn't.

When there's joint top ranking names, both queries should bring back all joint top results so there may not be exactly one answer. If you then just need a random single representative row from those result, look at using `select top 1`, perhaps adding `order by` to get the first alphabetically.

*Most popular by year regardless of gender:*

```
-- ONE PER YEAR:
SELECT n.Year, n.Name, n.Gender, n.Qty FROM Name n
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM Name n2
       WHERE n2.Year = n.Year
         AND n2.Qty > n.Qty
)
```

*Most popular by year for each gender:*

```
-- ONE PER GENDER PER YEAR:
SELECT n.Year, n.Name, n.Gender, n.Qty FROM Name n
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM Name n2
       WHERE n2.Year = n.Year
         AND n2.Gender = n.Gender
         AND n2.Qty > n.Qty
)
```

Performance is, despite the verbosity of the SQL, usually on a par with alternatives when using this pattern (often better).

There are other approaches, including using GROUP statements, but personally I find this one more readable and standard cross-DBMS.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.